# Conditionally include reference in Directory.Build.props using project name

Tags: .net, msbuild, csproj

My directory structure:

```
Directory.Build.props
Common
  Common.csproj
Project1
  Project1.csproj
Project2
  Project2.csproj
Project3
  Project3.csproj
```

I want the `Common` project referenced by all other projects, so I added this to  `Directory.Build.props`:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="../Common/Common.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

But that means the `Common` project references itself, so I get this error:

> error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "_GenerateRestoreProjectPathWalk".

I want to rewrite it to exclude the `Common` project, maybe using the project name somehow. Something like:

```xml
  <ProjectReference Include="../Common/Common.csproj" Condition="WHAT GOES HERE"/>
```

What do I put in `"WHAT GOES HERE"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check for a characteristic property from `Common.csproj` e.g. `<RootNamespace>`. Suppose `Common` project looked like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- ... -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>Common</RootNamespace>
    <!-- ... -->
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- ... -->
</Project>
```

The project reference in `Directory.Build.props` should be:

```
<ProjectReference Include="./Common/Common.csproj" Condition="'$(RootNamespace)' != 'Common'"/>
```

Comment: I'm a little unsure about the reference: Shouldn't it be `../Common/Common.csproj` because you're looking from the referencing project directory perspective instead of the solution directory perspective?

Comment: Thank you! I used `<ProjectReference Include="../Common/Common.csproj" Condition="'$(AssemblyName)' != 'Common'" />`